# How to find mode of multiple columns in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Input column example :

| ID | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat | cat | dog |
| 2 | dog | cat | dog |
| 3 | cat | cat | dog |
| 4 | bird | cat | dog |

Output column example :

| ID | Column A | Column B | Column C | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat | cat | dog | cat |
| 2 | dog | cat | dog | dog |
| 3 | cat | cat | dog | cat |
| 4 | bird | cat | bird | bird |

So far I have only calculated mode for a single column. Not sure how we can do it horizontally by combining 4 columns.

Comment: What happens if a given row has a tie of 2 values for the mode?  Also, what is the primary key of your table?

Comment: edited the example , you can check now . thank you

Answer (score 0):

We can use an unpivot approach with the help of a union query.  Then, use `ROW_NUMBER()` to select the mode:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, ColumnA AS val FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, ColumnB FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, ColumnC FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, val) cnt
    FROM cte
),
cte3 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY cnt DESC, val) rn
    FROM cte2
)

SELECT t1.ColumnA, t1.ColumnB, t1.ColumnC, t2.val AS Mode
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte3 t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t2.rn = 1
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

In the event that two or more values are tied for the mode, it breaks the tie by arbitrarily returning the alphabetically lower value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the built in MODE function for this, and Snowflake semi-structured functionality to unpivot and apply it. Check the behaviour of [MODE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/mode.html) suits your needs with regards to breaking ties and null handling etc.

First create test data like your example (please include code to repro in future!)

```
create view YOURTABLE as
select
  ID,
  COLUMN_A,
  COLUMN_B,
  COLUMN_C
from  (values
      (1,'cat','cat','dog'),
      (2,'dog','cat','dog'),
      (3,'cat','cat','dog'),
      (4,'bird','cat','dog')
      ) vw (ID, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C);
```

Here's the query to get your output;

```
with o_r as (Select ID, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C,
                    array_construct(COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C) arr_row from YOURTABLE )
    select ID, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, mode(value::VARCHAR) MODE  
      from o_r, lateral flatten (input => o_r.arr_row) lf
     group by 1,2,3,4
     order by 1;
```

Gather up the columns we want to calculate MODE over with array_construct(),lateral flatten the array, and then group by your ID, and columns with MODE on the flattened VALUE column.